# Requiere sudo asks password in a ComputeEngine instance providing access with OS Login

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm running an Ubuntu 20.04 instance in **Compute Engine** providing SSH access through **OS Login**.

User has set **Compute OS Admin Login** role and can run commands via sudo without specifying a password. Is there any way to change this? I would like sudo ask for user password.

I have changed all `ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL` occurrences by `ALL=(ALL) ALL` in `/etc/sudoers.d/*` and `/var/google-sudoers.d/username_domain_ext` files without success.

Any ideas?

If I comment `#includedir /var/google-sudoers.d` in `/etc/sudoers.d/google-oslogin` users lose privileges to run sudo. That leads me to think they must be something to do with `/var/google-sudoers.d/username_domain_ext` file to force sudo ask for a password.

Finally, `sudo -l` seems to return what I want:

```
username_domain_ext@hostname:~$ sudo -l
Matching Defaults entries for username_domain_ext on hostname:
    env_reset, mail_badpass, secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin\:/snap/bin

User username_domain_ext may run the following commands on hostname:
    (ALL : ALL) ALL
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is my understanding that there are no passwords (OS Login uses SSH keys). Are you setting user passwords on the instance somehow?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It has made me see the light. Although it is a Google Identity user with a password, it does not seem to work within the Compute instance. Trying to change password from shell throws this error: `passwd: Authentication token manipulation error` and `passwd: password unchanged`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/636092/how-to-get-sudo-to-prompt-you-for-a-password-each-time) of how to set sudo to prompt for password. You need to use the sudo visudo command

Comment: I already configured sudoers files as I wrote in my question. Seems like is not a sudo problem but with OS Login.

Comment: Are you logging in using SSH form Chrome? Can you try using a 3rd party tools? https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#thirdpartytools